# android R8 how to keep class name but not members

Tags: android, proguard, android-r8

Now I have an annotation named "ABC", I want to keep the classes which has a member annotated by "ABC" like

```
class Test {
  @ABC
  var testField: Int = 0
  
  var testField2: Int = 0
 }
```

I want to keep the class name "Test", but obfuscate the member name "testField", "testField2". Is there a way to do this?
Every insightful comment is highly appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
-if class com.example.* {
    @com.example.ABC <fields>;
}

-keepnames class com.example.*
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply this to the classes which is actually *used* in your program you can use this rule:

```
# For all classes used in the program keep and obfuscate fields annotated with @ABC.
-if class *
-keepclasseswithmembers,allowobfuscation class <1> {
  @ABC <fields>;
}
# Keep the class name for classes which has at least one used field annotated with @ABC.
-if class * {
  @ABC <fields>;
}
-keep class <1>
```

If you want it for all classes (not just the ones used in the program) remove the second line `-if class *`.

In the question only one field is annotated, and the above rules will only keep the annotated fields. If you want to keep all fields on classes where at least one field is annotated you will have to add the following rule as well:

```
# Keep all fields for classes which has at least one used field annotated with @ABC.
-if class * {
  @ABC <fields>;
}
-keep,allowobfuscation class <1> {
  <fields>;
}
```

If the annotation `ABC` has runtime retention and you want that annotation to stay for runtime reflection, you will have to add the following rules as well:

```
-keepattributes RuntimeVisibleAnnotations,AnnotationDefault
-keep @interface ABC
```

Finally please note that as the class is a Kotlin class, the fields also have generated getters and setters, which are not kept by any of the rules above. There is unfortunately no generic way of keeping the getters and setters for exactly the fields which are kept. The following rule will keep *all* public getters and setters on classes where at least one field is annotated with `@ABC`:

```
-if class * {
  @ABC <fields>;
}
-keep class <1> {
  public *** get*();
  public void set*(...);
}
```

However, this rule has the unfortunate side effect of keeping all the fields for these getters and setters, so if you only want to keep the fields annotated with `@ABC` this will not work.

It is possible to annotate getters and setters without supplying any code:

```
public class Test {
  @ABC var testField: Int = 0
  @ABC get
  @ABC set

  var testField2: Int = 0
 }
```

With that you can update the initial rules to be

```
-keepclasseswithmembers,allowobfuscation class <1> {
  @ABC <fields>;
  @ABC *** get*();
  @ABC void set*(***);
}
```

to only keep annotated fields and annotated getters and setters.